# Send email vbscript asp

Tags: email, vbscript, asp-classic

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS8.5
I trying to send email via CDo

```
<%

Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1 'Send message using the local SMTP service pickup directory. 
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network). 

Const cdoAnonymous = 0 'Do not authenticate
Const cdoBasic = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
Const cdoNTLM = 2 'NTLM

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
objMessage.Subject = "Example CDO Message" 
objMessage.From = "mymail@gmail.com" 
objMessage.To = "email@gmail.com" 
objMessage.TextBody = "This is some sample message text.." & vbCRLF & "It was sent using SMTP authentication."

'==This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 

'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

'Type of authentication, NONE, Basic (Base64 encoded), NTLM
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic

'Your UserID on the SMTP server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "myemail@gmail.com"

'Your password on the SMTP server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "mypass"

'Server port (typically 25)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 

'Use SSL for the connection (False or True)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False

'Connection Timeout in seconds (the maximum time CDO will try to establish a connection to the SMTP server)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

'==End remote SMTP server configuration section==

objMessage.Send
response.write objMessage.Err.number
%>
```

Response goes more than 84000 ms and I get error

```
Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0113'

Script timed out

/login.asp

The maximum amount of time for a script to execute was exceeded. You can change this limit by specifying a new value for the property Server.ScriptTimeout or by changing the value in the IIS administration tools.
```

Sending the same email with same code from VBA is OK without any error.

What is wrong?

Comment: The asp page took too long to execute, the default timeout is 90sec. this is always a pain when that happen because you don't have any line number to help, what we do here when it happens is save the time in a logfile at many different places in the code to identify which part of the code is taking too much time.
In the code you show, the only line that could take long i think is the Send, but i would be surprise it takes so much time, is there any other code in the page ? i doubt the problem is in the code you show

Comment: Only this code in the page, no one of existing CDO email send example not work for me

Comment: your smtpconnectiontimeout is 60, so it does not make any sense to take more than 90sec to execute since all other instructions are just property assignements. How is the request to the page made ? is it called directly from a browser or from another server-side script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of page you have to recall libreries:

```
<!--METADATA TYPE="typelib" UUID="CD000000-8B95-11D1-82DB-00C04FB1625D" NAME="CDO for Windows 2000 Type Library" -->
<!--METADATA TYPE="typelib" UUID="00000205-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4" NAME="ADODB Type Library" -->
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>
```

Then you can try to use this code:

```
Set email_info = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
            Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
            Set Flds = iConf.Fields
            Flds(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
            Flds(cdoSMTPServer) = "smtp.domain-name.ext" 
            Flds(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 25
            Flds(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoAnonymous ' 0
            Flds.Update
            Set email_info.Configuration = iConf
```